# Missing value in xml Unmarshal when custom type is nested

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

Firstly, I want to decode `<gd:name` into a struct, so I have:

```
type GDName struct {
    GivenName string `xml:"gd givenName"`
}
```

And then decode

```
    bs := []byte(`  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>FIRST_NAME</gd:givenName>
    </gd:name>
    `)

    var n GDName
    err := xml.Unmarshal(bs, &n)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", n)
```

However, when it comes to nested field xml string,

```
<entry>
 <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>FIRST_NAME</gd:givenName>
 </gd:name>
</entry>
```

and have

```
// ContactKind is the contact API used, atom-xml based structure.
// It represents a person's contact data. Such as address, name, email, etc...
// It contains private fields in the real structure.
type ContactKind struct {
    Name GDName
}

type decodeContactKind struct {
    Name GDName `xml:"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005 name"`
}

// UnmarshalXML implements xml.Unmarshaler.
// In the unmarhal processing, common element or server-only element will be read.
func (c *ContactKind) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var o decodeContactKind
    err := d.DecodeElement(&o, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    c.Name = GDName{
        GivenName: o.Name.GivenName,
    }

    return nil
}
```

It failed to decode the GDName stuff into `ContactKind.Name` field.
Here's the snippet and [go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/rIbZJMelF2I).

```
bs2 := []byte(`<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
<gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>FIRST_NAME</gd:givenName>
</gd:name></entry>`)

    var ct ContactKind
    err = xml.Unmarshal(bs2, &ct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", ct.Name)
```

I expected the second part will print the same thing as the first part did.

```
main.GDName{GivenName:"FIRST_NAME"}
```

I wonder why it can not work and how to fix it to unmarshal GDName into ContactKind's Name field.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine (root entry tag described with [xml.Name](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Marshal) field):

```
type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"entry"`
    Name    GDName   `xml:"name"`
}

type GDName struct {
    GivenName string `xml:"givenName"`
}
```

You can check it [here](https://go.dev/play/p/QkTQhSR9_Ou)